# SQL Server FORMAT create varchar with very large lenght

Tags: sql-server

It not really a problem but i am curious to know why.
I am using sql server and using `FORMAT` in a number returns a varchar with 4000 lenght. Why?

```
select format(1,'00')
```

This query returns "01"

Comment: Fair question.
"The length of the return value is determined by the format."
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#return-types

Comment: Of course if you change that input value to 999 you'll see that the output overflows the format string too.

Comment: It's .NET's String.Format, documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#the-0-custom-specifier

Comment: The actual length is 2 characters, 4000 is just the length of the data type

Answer (score 2):

Consider a query like

```
drop table if exists #t

create table #t(val int, fmt varchar(20))

insert into #t(val,fmt) values (1,'00')
insert into #t(val,fmt) values (1,'0000000')
insert into #t(val,fmt) values (1,'0000000000000000000')

select format(val,fmt) formatted from #t
```

What data type should `formatted` be?  It can't change per row, so a single type must be chosen to hold all the values.  And `nvarchar(4000)` is a reasonable choice, as it can hold any string with up to 4000 characters.